# After merging missing values have a spurious value

Tags: r, merge

After merging the resulting dataset doesn't have the same number of nonmissings (the variable on which I merge has no duplicates in either dataset), instead it has the same number of missings - meaning that I get 72229 spurious values, all exactly like one value in the second dataset.

There is just one row in the second dataset with that spurious value, and it looks perfectly normal. If I set its value to missing, I get the desired result (except for the one missing value). If I set its value to 1000, I get 72229 times 1000 in the result. So I thought it's something about that row, but if try to make a reproducible example using that row and some others, the error doesn't occur.
I was unsuccessful at making a reproducible example in a sufficiently small subset of the data, that I could comfortably share it, so I'm mostly soliciting sage advice. Advice on how to reproduce the problem would also be nice.

```
> table(is.na(cogdj$int.youth))
FALSE  TRUE 
 1731   178 
> sum(duplicated(soep$PERSNR))
[1] 0
> sum(duplicated(cogdj$PERSNR))
[1] 0
> soep = merge(soep,cogdj[,c('PERSNR','ana','ded','mat','ari','int.youth')],by="PERSNR",all.x=T,incomparables=NA)
> table(is.na(soep$int.youth))
FALSE  TRUE 
73959   178 
> nrow(soep[which(round(soep$int.youth,20)==1.6737269266506955567),])
[1] 72229
> nrow(cogdj[which(round(cogdj$int.youth,20)==1.6737269266506955567),])
[1] 1

> cogdj[which(round(cogdj$int.youth,20)==1.6737269266506955567),c('PERSNR','int.youth')]
  PERSNR int.youth
1 609104  1.673727
```

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example, with a minimal extract of your data that allows to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: merging on a numeric vector seems like a bad idea to me. floating errors, you know...

Comment: @juba I would like to, and I tried, but when I tried to simplify the problem and use a minimal dataset, the problem did not occur anymore. I suspect that if I had a reproducible example, I'd have the solution.

Comment: @flodel The numeric vector doesn't contain floating point numbers, only natural numbers. That said, I tried converting `PERSNR` to factor in both samples, the same problem occurs. Also, said problem does not occur with other merges on `PERSNR` either.

Comment: @Ruben: You have two choices: either keep making your minimal dataset more complicated until you encouter the problem, or keep simplifying your real dataset until the problem goes away.

Comment: @RichieCotton Or I just go with deleting said value and set it manually, that fixes the problem. Of course, I would like to figure out why this goes wrong, but I've already spent quite a lot of time on trying to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Also, @Ruben, you clearly are merging on floating point numbers.  You merge on `int.youth`, which you have to round to 20 dp (even though R's double precision numbers aren't accurate to more than 15 or 16 sig figs).

Comment: What about `sum(is.na(soep$PERSNR))` or `sum(is.na(cogdj$PERSNR))`? Having `NA`s there, and the fact you are using `incomparables=NA` could create these unexpected entries, maybe?

Comment: Richie, I also realized: he is not merging on `int.youth` but `PERSNR` which looks like integer. But the `20` digit precision being too much is a good point: Ruben, what numbers do you get if you use a `12`-digit precision test (assuming this is enough precision to isolate the "spurious" number from all others.)?

Comment: @flodel @Richie Sorry for the delay, had to go to lunch. flodel ist correct, I merge on `PERSNR`, which is an integer (using a factor doesn't help). `int_youth` is a floating point number, but rounding it doesn't fix the merge bug. I also don't get more matches for the offending number in `cogdj` if I use fewer digits (I just wanted to illustrate that this is really the same value). Removing `incomparables=NA` doesn't change the problem either. There are no missings in `PERSNR`.